# Using nested spawn method in expect scripts

Tags: ssh, nested, expect, spawning

I have written following expect script:

```
/usr/bin/expect<<EOF
set SERVER_HOSTNAME "$env(SERVER_HOSTNAME)"

set USERNAME "$env(USERNAME)"
set PASSWORD "$env(PASSWORD)"

set timeout -1

spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
expect  {
        "Host key verification failed." { spawn ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"; expect "known_hosts.old"; send_user "Updated host key details."; exp_continue}
        "continue connecting (yes/no)" { send "yes\r"; expect "Permanently added"; exp_continue}
        "assword:" { send_user "Keygen details are correctly mapped for this server\n"}
        }
EOF
```

Here I want that if the host key of a server can't be verified while spawing "ssh" process, then the nested spawn process "ssh-keygen -R" should remove old key. Then the "ssh" process should try to connect again so that new key can be added corresponding to that server.

But here, after the execution of:

```
send_user "Updated host key details."
```

method, expect process is exiting out from this script.

I know the alternative can be to divide this expect call into two steps, as follows:

```
 /usr/bin/expect<<EOF
set SERVER_HOSTNAME "$env(SERVER_HOSTNAME)"

set USERNAME "$env(USERNAME)"
set PASSWORD "$env(PASSWORD)"

set timeout -1

spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
expect  {
        "Host key verification failed." { spawn ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"; expect "known_hosts.old"; send_user "Updated host key details."; exp_continue}            
        "continue connecting (yes/no)" { send "yes\r"; expect "Permanently added"; exp_continue}
       "assword:" { send_user "Keygen details are correctly mapped for this server\n"}
        }


spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
expect  {           
        "continue connecting (yes/no)" { send "yes\r"; expect "Permanently added"; exp_continue}
        "assword:" { send_user "Keygen details are correctly mapped for this server\n"}
        }

EOF
```

But do we have a way to execute this expect call in one go. In nutshell, I want to know, can we do the nesting of spawn process?

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace goes a long way toward maintainable code: you don't need to squish so many commands per line.

```
spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
expect {
    "Host key verification failed." {
        spawn ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
        expect "known_hosts.old"
        send_user "Updated host key details."
        exp_continue
    }
    "continue connecting (yes/no)" {
        send "yes\r"
        expect "Permanently added"
        exp_continue
    }
    "assword:" { 
        send_user "Keygen details are correctly mapped for this server\n"
    }
}
```

I this case, you don't need to interact with ssh-keygen, so use [`exec`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) to simply call it

```
    "Host key verification failed." {
        exec ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
        puts "Updated host key details."
        exp_continue
    }
```

If you need to spawn something and interact with it, you need to know that there is an implicit variable, `spawn_id`, created by spawn, and used by expect and send. You'll need to save the spawn_id of the current process before you spawn any other process. For example:

```
spawn process1
set ids(1) $spawn_id
expect -i $ids(1) "some pattern"
send -i $ids(1) "some string\r"

spawn process2
set ids(2) $spawn_id
expect -i $ids(2) "some pattern from process2"
send -i $ids(2) "some string to process2\r"
```

Comment: How can I use exp_continue after process 2. For e.g. if I want to write a script as follows:

 spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
 set ids(1) $spawn_id
 expect  {
   "Host key verification failed." {spawn ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"; expect "known_hosts.old"; send_user "Updated host key details."; exp_continue -i $ids(1)}
   "continue connecting (yes/no)" { spawn $ScriptsDir/TestProcess; send -i $ids(1) "yes\r"; expect -i $ids(1) "Permanently added"; exp_continue -i $ids(1)}
   "assword:" { send_user "Keygen details are correctly mapped for this server\n"}
   }        
 EOF

Comment: In above case I am getting following error message:
 "usage: exp_continue [-continue_timer]

    while executing
"exp_continue -i (1)"

I have initialized ids array as: 
array set ids { 1 "" }

Comment: This is due to the way you are mixing expect code into a shell script. Do you notice how `$ids(1)` got turned into `(1)`? That's the shell substituting the variables *before* expect starts. Change your heredoc to use single quotes so the shell does not touch the expect variables: ` /usr/bin/expect <<'EOF'`

Comment: I used exec command also as follows:

spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
set ids(1) $spawn_id
expect  {
        "Host key verification failed." {exec ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME";  puts "Updated host key details."; exp_continue}
        "continue connecting (yes/no)" { send "yes\r"; expect "Permanently added"; exp_continue}
        "assword:" { send_user "Keygen details are correctly mapped for this server\n"}
        }        
EOF

Comment: I got following output:
<file path>/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as <file path>/.ssh/known_hosts.old
    while executing
"exec ssh-keygen -R "hostname""
    invoked from within
"expect  {
        "Host key verification failed." {exec ssh-keygen -R "hostname";  puts "Updated host key details."; exp_continue}
        "continue c..."

Here I wanted that the second statement of expect script should also execute which didn't happen:
  
"continue connecting (yes/no)" { send "yes\r"; expect "Permanently added"; exp_continue}

Do we have a way to make it possible?

Comment: Either ssh-keygen returned with a non-zero exit status, or it printed something on stderr. Both of those cases cause `exec` to think that some error occurred with the external command, and you'll get "child process exited abnormally. Investigate the Tcl `catch` command ([here](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm) and [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/902))

Comment: I tried to use single quotes around heredoc, but then I got following error: 

usr/bin/expect<<EOF
set SERVER_HOSTNAME "$env(SERVER_HOSTNAME)"...

array set ids { 1 "" }

spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
set ids(1) $spawn_id 
expect { 
  "verification failed." {spawn ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"; expect "known_hosts.old"; send_user "Updated..."; exp_continue -i $ids(1)} 
  "(yes/no)" { spawn ./TestProcess; send -i $ids(1) "yes\r"; expect -i $ids(1) "Permanently"; exp_continue -i $ids(1)} 
  "assword:" { send_user "Keygen..."} }
EOF: No such file or directory

Comment: Then I tried to use reverse quote, but here I think that expect script is  executed in different shell, and nothing is printed on my screen.

Comment: I have updated my expect script with catch statement as follows:
 spawn ssh "$USERNAME@$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
set ids(1) $spawn_id 
expect  {
        "Host key verification failed." {
        if {[catch {exec ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"} excuse]} {
        puts "Updated host key details with exception "
  } else {
         puts "Updated host key details.";
  };  exp_continue}
        "continue connecting (yes/no)" { send "yes\r"; expect "Permanently added"; exp_continue}
        ...
        }
Still, exp_continue is not working and script is just moving out of expect statement.

Comment: No, just put quotes around the first "EOF" like I showed. Ah, I see my formatting was bad. Like this: `/usr/bin/expect <<'EOF'  # see the quotes only needed here`

Comment: After updating EOF as 'EOF', Still I am getting following error:
usage: exp_continue [-continue_timer]

    while executing
"exp_continue -i $ids(1)"
    invoked from within
"expect { 
  "Host key verification failed." {spawn ssh-keygen -R "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"; expect "known_hosts.old"; send_user "Updated host key details."; ..."

Comment: check your expect documentation. does `exp_continue` take a `-i` option?

Comment: Yes that's true, exp_continue only takes [-continue_timer]  as option. So how  can we call exp_continue for Process1, after running spawn command for Process2 ?

Comment: Try `set spawn_id $ids(1); exp_continue`